# How can I determine which type of Office document a macro is running against?

Tags: vba, ms-office

In a macro, I need to either use `ActiveDocument` (Word), `ActiveWorkbook` (Excel) or `ActivePresentation` (PowerPoint), but first I need to determine which application is running.

How can I find out which type of Office document a macro is running on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to get the name of whatever application is running:

```
MsgBox Application.Name
```

Comment: Thanks, this works with InStr. I'll leave the question open a bit though.

Comment: what are you trying to do this for? What is the use of `ActiveXXXXX` ?